# Ad Script Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, scripting, ads

So I have this thing called "AdHitz" on my website (I'm not old enough for AdSense), and I need to put ad code on every page in order for it to work. The thing is, you have to change the script link from time to time, and I didn't want to have to edit every single webpage every time the link changed, so here's what I did:

Original:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adhitzads.com/745025"></script>
```

Newer:

```
<script id="ad1"></script>
```

In the CSS Stylesheet file:

```
#ad1 {
    type="text/javascript";
    src="http://adhitzads.com/745025";
}
```

The thing is, the ads are no longer showing up! What should I do?

Comment: I think you're confused about a few things. But I don't know where to start to put you back on the right track. let me try to get a few links together.

Comment: Are... are you trying to set the source with CSS? D:

Comment: Why don't you just include a footer on each page?

Comment: Please don't think these are patronizing: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/basic-structure-of-a-web-page/  --  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html  --  and the more encompassing http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: as per your issue, once you understand where you goofed up the code above, I recommend looking at a templating system (client or server side could work)

Comment: Basically, you're confusing CSS properties with JavaScript properties. CSS can't touch the script elements properties, only it's style properties. You're going to have to write a script that will alter the source depending on the page

Answer (score 1):

Here do this.. Include this script tag on each one of your pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ads.js"></script>
```

Then make a file called ads.js and put this in it

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://adhitzads.com/745025";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Then everytime your ad company changes your url, just open ads.js and change the URL there.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use a server side include to put the script on each page.

You could put your script into a script file (ad-script.js, the name does not matter) and include it in your pages like this:

```
<script src="ad-file.js">
```

You could also create a file like ad-file.html and then paste the script into it. Then include it in each page like this:

```
  <!--#include file="ad-file.html" -->
```

Also, CSS is a styling language, so it cannot handle scripting.

Answer (score -2):

You seem to be confused about how CSS works.  While your CSS correctly targets elements with the ID of "ad1", CSS is formatted like "display: none;" and not with equal signs.  Secondly, 'type' and 'src' are more than likely not valid CSS attributes that you can modify.

I understand that you are worried about having to change this link on multiple pages.  If you want another way to solve this problem, you can use PHP for your website, and make a PHP file for the portion of your website that has the Javascript includes.  Then all you have to do is edit the one PHP file and every site will include that one file.  Alternatively, you can use a better and free text editor, such as KomodoEdit, to do a mass replace with very little trouble or time required.